# How to scrape a very nested element on a page with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm scraping [this page](https://higher.gs.com/results?&page=1&sort=RELEVANCE) for jobs. However, I'm having some trouble properly getting and scraping an element describing job positions (Analyst, Vice President, Associate, etc.).

To get to the job card, I'm using full XPATH (which already looks messy but I have no idea how else to do it). The code is:

```
checked = wait.until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
            (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="__next"]/main/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div'))
    )
```

And then to get the text inside these elements:
[image]

What should I do? I tried using XPATH again, but it just gets the first element's info, and repeats. For example:

```
jobs = []
for row in checked:
    jobs.append({
        'info': row.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="__next"]/main/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[1]/a/div/div[2]/span[2]').text
    })
print(jobs)
```

Just gives me this result:

```
[{'info': 'Analyst'}, {'info': 'Analyst'}, {'info': 'Analyst'}, {'info': 'Analyst'}, {'info': 'Analyst'}, {'info': 'Analyst'}, {'info': 'Analyst'}, {'info': 'Analyst'}, {'info': 'Analyst'}, {'info': 'Analyst'}]
```

How do I properly get the XPATH for all these elements? What's a more cleaner approach? I tried `By.CSS_SELECTOR`, too. But the elements are so nested with generic classes which repeat, that I have no clue how to approach this.

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you look for a `<span>` with attribute `data-gs-uitk-component` equal to `text`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locator of position has several levels.

1st level is job card that can be located by attribute `//*[@data-gs-uitk-component='card-body']`

2nd level is element `//*[contains(@class,'align-items-center')` that contains child `.//*[@data-type='custom']`.

3rd level is needed element that `data-gs-uitk-component` attribute equals `text`.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://higher.gs.com/results?&page=1&sort=RELEVANCE")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
job_cards = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@data-gs-uitk-component='card-body']//*[contains(@class,'align-items-center') and .//*[@data-type='custom']]//*[@data-gs-uitk-component='text']")))

for card in job_cards:
    print(card.text)
```

Comment: Thank you, Yaroslavm!! This clarified how I can apply a much cleaner approach.